# Flip + 3d transformation of some child element (chrome bug?)

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

Im trying to make 3d flip

http://jsfiddle.net/ergmt3zv/3/

And everything is pretty fine, but when I add 3d transform to some child element

```
transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
```

on first flip back side doesn't animate.

http://jsfiddle.net/ergmt3zv/2/

Is this a bug or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Happens in Firefox too, so it might not be a bug.

Comment: checked the work, what is wrong with this turn? maybe you need the other way?

Comment: @Klaster_1, in Firefox animation is flat, but back side is animating.

Comment: @AlexWilson, Im checking in chrome 37. "maybe you need the other way?" - another way of what?

Comment: well, such as not from left to right and top to bottom

Comment: @AlexWilson, I need both